# How to display a button in header on only one specific page

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I have added a button of apply now it my header but I just want to display this button on only one page which is register. I do not want this button to appear on other pages of website. When user go to the register page this button should automatically appear in header. So how can I do it?
Below is the code which I used to display the button but this button is displaying on the page not in the header section:

```
if ( $current_url == 'umacollege.geekss.com.au/register' ) {
echo '<div class="entry-banner">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="entry-banner-content">
    
<h1><button type="button">Click Me!</button></h1>
</div></div></div>';
}
```

Comment: just add if condition like `if(is_page(your_page_id))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the id of register page. Suppose it is 1675, write following CSS:

```
.header-menu-btn {display: none !important}
.page-id-1675 .header-menu-btn {display: inline !important}
```

Comment: I have tried it but its not working here is the class of my button header-menu-btn I used it instead of button and changes the page id and added it in my additional custom css but nothing changes

Comment: Can you send a link?

Comment: yes here is the link https://umacollege.geekss.com.au/register

Comment: I have used your updated answer but still its not working

Comment: style is not applied to https://umacollege.geekss.com.au/register

Comment: brother I have copy pasted the above code in customize section where we add additional css and then published it but still style is not applying

Comment: try adding style using this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-css/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242710/discussion-between-gakhar-and-narek-malkhasyan).

Answer (score 2):

You can hide the button in the pages you don't want it by aiming the url path with jQuery

```js
jQuery(function ($){
        var pathname = window.location.pathname;
        if (pathname == "/page2/"){
           $(".your_button_class").css("display","none");
          }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use strpos to check the text is contains or not.

```
if ( strpos($current_url, 'umacollege.geekss.com.au/register') == true ) {}
```

If you are using wordpress then best option is to use is_page() function.

```
if ( is_page( 'register') ) {} // slug
```

or

```
if ( is_page( 1675 ) ) {} // page id
```